# Questions based on a puzzle book

Tags: discussion, policy

(A few [related](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1608/legal-to-use-pokemon-etc-as-themes-for-challenges) [meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2040/contests-questions-based-on-external-games) [questions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/what-are-the-policies-for-threads-relating-to-facebook-puzzles-project-euler-u))

I know of a couple logic puzzles that I think would make good questions for this site. However, they are not original to me. I got them from [this puzzle book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0806941995). **With proper source attribution, can I base challenges on them?**

Considerations **for**:

- Some of the puzzles in the book are evidently adapted from other sources already. For example, one is a generalized form of Sudoku.
- I've found [several](http://www.sachsentext.de/en/taxonomy/term/54) of the [puzzle](http://valezius.blogspot.com/2013/05/rules-half-dominoes.html) [types](http://valezius.blogspot.com/2013/05/rules-tents_6.html) from the book [online](http://puzzleparasite.blogspot.com/2011/10/rules-turning-fences.html) already.
- I am not using any of the exact puzzles from the book (I don't actually have it anymore), just the puzzle rules. Together with the non-commercial nature of the site, I believe such a use falls under [Fair Use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) guidelines.

Considerations **against**:

- The book is, of course, copyrighted. Furthermore, using puzzles from a puzzle book seems to me (not that I'm a lawyer) like a larger borrowing than using names of Pokémons, e.g. On the other hand, apparently [game mechanics are not copyrightable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2041/16766). Not sure how much that applies to puzzle mechanics.

What say ye?

Comment: I think a lot of this will depend on how much is changed, to be honest. I realize you're not talking about a copy/paste job here, but there's a whole spectrum. If you show an example of what you want to post, side by side with the original puzzle for comparison, you might get a better answer.

Comment: @Geobits Hmm. Well, as far as the *rules* of the puzzle go, it *is* essentially a copy/paste job--I'd specify them in my own words, of course, but they would be the same rules, with the added sentence "Write a program to solve this puzzle."  The main change would be that I wouldn't use any of the (hand-crafted?) specific puzzles from the book as test cases, but would create or generate my own examples.

Comment: For an example, take [this puzzle](http://www.sachsentext.de/en/node/472) (another one found in the book under discussion, BTW).  My hypothetical question here would 1) state the rules given in the opening paragraph, though written in my own words; 2) ask for a program/function to solve such a puzzle; 3) specify I/O format, etc.; 4) give a couple of example puzzles and solutions created by me.

Comment: Beware, however that [tag:fixed-output] puzzles don't go down well. [I learned that the hard way](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/a-decent-decade), after taking the puzzle from a maths puzzle book.

Comment: @BetaDecay Yeah, I can see why that's the case.  None of these puzzles are that way, though.  They're more like Sudoku, where different configurations lead to different puzzles.

Comment: @DLosc I see. Tbh, I don't think MENSA will bother hunting you down to sue you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, game mechanics are not copyrightable. So long as you only use the mechanics, and not the exact puzzles, you're in the clear.